# Changed Macro definition reverts to original

Tags: environments, description

I have two commands `\testone` and `\testtwo`. `\testtwo` appears only if there was a relevant `\testone` before and takes the same arguments. Hence I want `\testone` to store its arguments in `\@repeat@me` where `\testtwo` picks them up again so I don't have to type them twice.

However, this works only if both are in the same environment. But in some cases it decides that the changed value of `\@repeat@me` should be ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\def\@repeat@me{}

\newcommand\testtwo{\bf{\@repeat@me}% print what is currently defined.
% reset the definition so it does not interfere with next call
\def\@repeat@me{}}

% print it and then remember it.
\newcommand\testone[1]{\def\@repeat@me{#1}\emph{\@repeat@me}}%

\makeatother
\begin{document}

% prints: \emph{Hello World} \bf{Hello World}
\testone{Hello World} \testtwo{}

% prints: \bf{\emph{Hello World}}
% intended: \bf{\emph{Hello World}} \bf{Hello World}
\bf{\testone{Hello World}} \testtwo{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\global\def` instead of `\def` inside `\testone` definition. By the way, `\bf` takes no argument, hence `{\bf blah}` is the “more correct” syntax (better `\bfseries` or even `\textbf{..}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a global assignment (to escape groups and environments, you need) `\global\def` (or `\gdef`):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@repeat@me{}
\newcommand*\testtwo{\textbf{\@repeat@me}\gdef\@repeat@me{}}
\newcommand\testone[1]{\gdef\@repeat@me{#1}\emph{\@repeat@me}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\testone{Hello World} \testtwo
\textbf{\testone{Hello World}} \testtwo

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that TeX enforces a scope within which (re)definitions may live and be reverted outside. That's what happening here. Let's look at the expansions:

```
\testone{Hello World} \testtwo{}
```

expands to (with comments)

```
\def\@repeat@me{Hello World}\emph{\@repeat@me} % \testone{Hello World}
\textbf{\@repeat@me}\def\@repeat@me{}% \testtwo{}
```

which expands to

```
\emph{Hello World} \textbf{Hello World}% Using the new definition of \@repeat@me
```

[image]

Now look at the expansions of the second set of macros:

```
\textbf{\testone{Hello World}} \testtwo{}
```

expands to (with comments)

```
\textbf{% <--- start of a group/scope
  def\@repeat@me{Hello World}\emph{\@repeat@me}% \testone{Hello World}
} % <--- end of a group/scope
\textbf{\@repeat@me}\def\@repeat@me{}% \testtwo{}
```

which expands to

```
\textbf{\emph{Hello World}} % At scope-end, \@repeat@me reverts to its original definition
\textbf{}% Since \@repeat@me is empty {}
```

[image]

Using a global definition like `\gdef` makes the redefinition of `\@repeat@me` survive beyond the scope provided by `\textbf{..}`.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\def\@repeat@me{}

% print it and then remember it.
\newcommand\testone[1]{\gdef\@repeat@me{#1}\emph{\@repeat@me}}%

\newcommand\testtwo{\textbf{\@repeat@me}% print what is currently defined.
  % reset the definition so it does not interfere with next call
  \def\@repeat@me{}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

% prints: \emph{Hello World} \textbf{Hello World}
\testone{Hello World} \testtwo{}

% prints: \textbf{\emph{Hello World}} \textbf{Hello World}
\textbf{\testone{Hello World}} \testtwo{}

\end{document}
```